# How do I left join a field that has two combined values baked into a single varchar field?

Tags: mysql

foos.bar_slash_otherstuff is a varchar that looks like this:

```
bar/otherstuff
```

bars.bar is a varchar that looks like this:

```
bar
```

Now I need to left join this madness. And I am not allowed to use a temp table for this...

```
   select 
        `foos`.`bar_slash_otherstuff`,
        `bars`.`bar`
    from 
        `foos`
    left join 
        `bars` 
         on `bars`.`bar` = LEFT(`foos`.`bar_slash_otherstuff`, LOCATE('/', `foos`.`bar_slash_otherstuff`) - 1)
```

This works, but is this a decent way of achieving this or is there something out there more optimal?

Comment: I think you start by finding and flogging the guy that baked two values into one field. ;)

Comment: @TecBrat He's my boss. So I guess I need to find the 'How do I flog my boss without getting fired' post.

Comment: Oh, that's a tough one. "Legacy code" or "Legacy Design" can be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a 2-step process where the first step is a query that splits the bar_slash_otherstuff field and the second step performs the join you described above.

Comment: How do I do that without temp tables?

Comment: The first step is a query, so technically it's a temp table (cursor)  but you'll never see it. There's no cleanup if that's what you're concerned about.